Spotify Playback Engine on Web Radio Player Falls Back to Default Engine After 401/403 Errors – Seeking Reliable Auto-Reconnect Solution
We’ve developed a web radio player that integrates Spotify’s playback engine, allowing us to use Spotify for streaming and monetization when a user links their Spotify account. When the Spotify account is linked, the player should switch from our default playback engine to Spotify's playback engine for eligible tracks. However, we’re encountering intermittent issues where the player falls back to the default engine due to 401 Unauthorized or 403 Forbidden errors.
Once this fallback occurs, the player stays in default mode, even though the user’s Spotify account remains linked and tracks that are eligible for Spotify playback are played. We’d like the player to automatically retry and reconnect to the Spotify playback engine when these errors arise, but it seems to get “stuck” on the default engine instead.
Steps to Reproduce:
Open the web radio player and link a Spotify account.

Start playback with the Spotify engine.

Wait until the player encounters one of the following errors:
    401 Unauthorized – possibly related to token expiration or issues with refreshing.
    403 Forbidden – potentially related to permissions, usage limits, or unhandled playback state issues.

Once these errors are encountered, the playback engine switches to the default mode.

Even after several eligible tracks are played, the playback engine does not revert to Spotify.

Expected Behavior:
When Spotify playback is enabled, the player should remain connected to Spotify’s playback engine. If a connection error occurs (e.g., 401 or 403), the player should automatically reconnect and resume playback on Spotify for eligible tracks, rather than remaining on the default engine.
Technical Details:
We are using Spotify’s Web Playback SDK, following the documentation for OAuth token handling and auto-refresh.
Our token refresh process follows the guidelines from this Spotify Community post.
We’ve verified that tokens are attached to the Authorization header as Bearer <access_token> and that we’re requesting the appropriate scopes (e.g., user-read-playback-state, streaming, user-modify-playback-state).

Troubleshooting Steps Taken:
Token Refreshing: Implemented token refresh using Spotify’s guidelines (see link above). Despite this, we still encounter 401 errors intermittently, suggesting tokens might not be refreshing consistently or at the right intervals.
Scope and Permissions Check: Verified that the necessary scopes are requested during login, and ensured that the player initiates playback correctly when Spotify is first linked.
Fallback Handling: Attempted to implement a retry mechanism to reconnect to Spotify after a fallback, but this has not successfully resumed Spotify playback.

Questions for the Community:
Has anyone encountered similar 401 or 403 errors with the Spotify Web Playback SDK, despite using the recommended token auto-refresh flow?
Are there recommended strategies or patterns to ensure the player reliably reconnects to Spotify after fallback, rather than staying on the default playback engine?
Could there be any underlying rate limits or specific conditions (e.g., regional restrictions) that might cause the 403 errors intermittently?
Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated – thank you in advance!
